# How can I inject build.config variables into my build.gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I added my one signal app id to environment variables in `gradle.properties` file. I want to  call this variable in my gradle file from my `build.gradle` auto generated file. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To read a value inside the `build.properties` is quite simple.
For example:

In `gradle.properties`:

```
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=27
```

In your `build.gradle` you can use:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
}
```

Comment: Gabrielle I'm  talking about  reading  the build.config auto generated file  values  in  the build.gradle . I know how  to read  values from  build.properties file . thanks for your  reply :)